# Python urllib2 URLError exception?

Tags: python, networking, urllib2

I installed Python 2.6.2 earlier on a Windows XP machine and run the following code:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

page = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
urllib2.urlopen( page )
```

I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
  File "C:\Python26\test3.py", line 6, in <module><br>
    urllib2.urlopen( page )<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen<br>
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 383, in open<br>
    response = self._open(req, data)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 401, in _open<br>
    '_open', req)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain<br>
    result = func(*args)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1130, in http_open<br>
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1105, in do_open<br>
    raise URLError(err)<br>
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed><br><br><br>
```

Comment: What happens when you try a URL that exists?  The error you've posted smells like a proxy/firewall issue to me.  I will not submit an answer because I'm really not qualified to debug these things, but I'm hoping this comment will point network-knowledgeable people in a more fruitful direction than "your code is wrong" and "your URL doesn't exist".

Answer (score 4):

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
html = response.read()
```

You're doing it wrong.

Comment: Now i get this error:<br><br>

Traceback (most recent call last):<br>
...
    '_open', req)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain<br>
    result = func(*args)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1130, in http_open<br>
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)<br>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1105, in do_open<br>
    raise URLError(err)<br>
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed><br><br><br>

Thanks for the help.

Comment: That could be because the URL you gave doesn't exist (try visiting it). Use something else that does.

Comment: Downvoted because it doesn't address the real problem.  I am using 2.6.1 on WinXP (exact same urllib2.py, I checked) and when I execute DJDonaL3000's code, I get the expected urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look in the urllib2 source, at the line specified by the traceback:

```
File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 1105, in do_open
raise URLError(err)
```

There you'll see the following fragment:

```
    try:
        h.request(req.get_method(), req.get_selector(), req.data, headers)
        r = h.getresponse()
    except socket.error, err: # XXX what error?
        raise URLError(err)
```

So, it looks like the source is a socket error, not an HTTP protocol related error. Possible reasons: you are not on line, you are behind a restrictive firewall, your DNS is down,...

All this aside from the fact, as [mcandre](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290142/python-urllib2-problem/1290165#1290165) pointed out, that your code is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Name resolution error.

`getaddrinfo` is used to resolve the hostname (`python.org`)in your request. If it fails, it means that the name could not be resolved because:

1. It does not exist, or the records are outdated (unlikely; python.org is a well-established domain name)
2. Your DNS server is down (unlikely; if you can browse other sites, you should be able to fetch that page through Python)
3. A firewall is blocking Python or your script from accessing the Internet (most likely; Windows Firewall sometimes does not ask you if you want to allow an application)
4. You live on an ancient voodoo cemetery. (unlikely; if that is the case, you should move out)

Answer (score 1):

Windows Vista, python 2.6.2

It's a 404 page, right?

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import urllib
>>>
>>> page = urllib2.Request('http://www.python.org/fish.html')
>>> urllib2.urlopen( page )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 124, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 389, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 502, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 427, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 361, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\urllib2.py", line 510, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

DJ

First, I see no reason to import urllib; I've only ever seen urllib2 used to replace urllib entirely and I know of no functionality that's useful from urllib and yet is missing from urllib2.

Next, I notice that http://www.python.org/fish.html gives a 404 error to me.  (That doesn't explain the backtrace/exception you're seeing.  I get `urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

Normally if you just want to do a default fetch of a web pages (without adding special HTTP headers, doing doing any sort of POST, etc) then the following suffices:

```
req = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.python.org/')
html = req.read()
# and req.close() if you want to be pedantic
```