# SUDS client gets urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed (Python3.2 + WCF WS)

Tags: python, wcf, web-services, suds

I have a problem with connecting to web service with python3.2 (SUDS library 0.4.1). When I connect to the non-wcf webservice everything works fine. I create the object Client class like this:

```python
Client("http://xxxxxx.xx/XXX_2.0/RequestsService.asmx?wsdl")
```

But... I want to do exactly the same for wcf service:

```python
Client("http://xxxxxx.xx/XXX_2.0_WCF/WcfJSONRequestsService.svc?wsdl")
```

I get the following error:

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\client.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\reader.py", line 152, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.build_schema()
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\wsdl.py", line 248, in build_schema
    self.schema = container.load(self.options)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\xsd\schema.py", line 93, in load
    child.open_imports(options)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\xsd\schema.py", line 302, in open_imports
    imported = imp.open(options)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 570, in open
    result = self.download(options)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\xsd\sxbasic.py", line 588, in download
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\reader.py", line 79, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\reader.py", line 95, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\transport\https.py", line 60, in open
    return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\transport\http.py", line 63, in open
    return self.u2open(u2request)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\suds_jurko-0.4.1.jurko.5._development_-py3.2.egg\suds\transport\http.py", line 121, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 369, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 387, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1156, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1139, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Looks like a Windows related problem to me. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290142/python-urllib2-problem

Comment: This would suggest that the execution of `urllib.request.urlopen("http://xxxxxx.xx/XXX_2.0_WCF/WcfJSONRequestsService.svc?wsdl")` will result with a similar error (**urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed**). I checked to see what happens and... `urllib.request.urlopen()` not returned 404. This webservice exists and passed performance tests with JMeter. Then there were no problems with the connection.